# Optimize speed between application and dbhost

Tags: mysql, optimization, netbeans, connection

How to optimize the speed between a JAVA application (written in Netbeans) and my MYSQL Database (hosted at an external DB provider)?

Let's say I have the following code;

```
private void fillPlayersList()
{
    try
    {
        PlayerListModel.clear();
        Connection userConn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
        Statement userStat = userConn.createStatement();
        String userquery = "SELECT * FROM player";
        ResultSet userResult = userStat.executeQuery(userquery);
        if(userResult.next())
        {
            PlayerList.setEnabled(true);
            userResult.previous();
            while (userResult.next()) {
                int id = userResult.getInt("player_id");
                String username = userResult.getString("username");
                String ip = userResult.getString("ip");
                PlayerListModel.addElement(new PlayerItem(id, username, ip));
            }
        }
        userConn.close();
        PlayerList.setModel(PlayerListModel);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

It takes aaaggeeesss before this has been completed! How can I optimize a code like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have lots of records coming back? If you run the same query via some other tool, and bring back all the records, is that slow too? How long does it take if you fetch the first (say) 10 rows and stop? Does that take ages too?

Comment: If I do the same query in MYSQLWorkbench it's still quite slow, yes.

Comment: If fetching even a single row takes long, then the only thing one might be able to tweak are the parms on the connection (if any are allowed). What about some type of caching solution (say ehcache) so that you don't have to go to the database that often?

Answer (score 0):

you can start by **fetching only the fields you need**

```
SELECT player_id, username, ip FROM player
```

And probably add an where condition would also be good, **do you really need all the players**?

if you do **disable also the cursor**, and keep doing what you were doing...

```
    Statement userStat = userConn.createStatement();
    userStat.setFetchSize(0);
    String userquery = "SELECT player_id, username, ip  FROM player";
    ResultSet userResult = userStat.executeQuery(userquery);
```

Comment: Ye I really need all the players ;), to put them all in a list.

Comment: then fetch only the fields you need, a select * will return you more fields than what you need.

Comment: Done that, improved abit but it's still slow ;) Is this a cause that lays at the end of the DB?

Comment: BTW I updated the answer with instructions to disable the cursor and fetch all the results into cache...